# WPF MVVM custom Sorting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, sorting, mvvm

I am trying to create custom sorting WPF Data Grid. I have did database call on every sorting. I have used MVVM for this.

Issue is I am always getting Sort Direction of column always null on sorting event when I make DB Call. If I remove UpdateData method from sorting event it will work fine.  So By default it will sort always ascending order as per my code. Can anyone help me to get Sort Direction alternatively ASC and DESC please?

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"   ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"  GridLinesVisibility="All"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" BorderThickness="1"  IsReadOnly="True"  >
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="ADD" Command="{Binding AddNewPersonCommand}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="../Icons/Add.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0"   />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="EDIT" Command="{Binding EditPersonCommand}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="../Icons/edit.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0"    />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="DELETE">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="../Icons/delete.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0"   />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditPersonCommand}"  />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Sorting">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PersonGridSortingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Record ID" SortMemberPath="RecordID" Binding="{Binding RecordID}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding= "{Binding LAST_NAME}" Width="*"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="2nd Last Name" Binding= "{Binding SecondLastName}" Width="*"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding= "{Binding FIRST_NAME}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Of Birth" Binding= "{Binding Date_Of_Birth}"  Width="*"   />
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Town" Binding= "{Binding PrimaryAddress.City}" Width="*"   />-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    private ICollectionView _collectionView;

    public ICollectionView CollectionView
    {
        get
        {
            return _collectionView;
        }
        set
        {
            _collectionView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CollectionView");
        }
    }




    public async Task UpdateData(string sortCoulmnName = null, string sortDirection = null)
    {
        var lstPersons = await PersonDAO.SelectAll(PagerViewModel.CurrentPage, PagerViewModel.PageSize, sortCoulmnName, sortDirection);
        if (lstPersons.DataSource != null) { }
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonDTO>((PersonListDTO)lstPersons.DataSource);
        CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons);                    
    }

    public async void Sorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        e.Column.SortDirection = direction;
        string dir = direction.ToString() == "Ascending" ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        await UpdateData(e.Column.SortMemberPath, dir);
        CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, direction));

    }
```

Comment: Aren't you double-sorting the collection? First inside the `UpdateData` method (I guess) and then adding the SortDescription to the collection view?

Comment: I have paging of 20 records in the datagrid but I want to sort from all records of database table. So I am using UpdateData method to get sorted data from databse from whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're marking the event as Handled (`e.Handled = true`), you're effectively preventing the DataGrid from sorting and the SortDirection is never changing.

You'll have to manage the sort direction yourself. But it should be as easy as this:

```
private ListSortDirection lastSortDirection;

private string lastSortMemberPath;

public async void Sorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == lastSortMemberPath)
    {
        if (lastSortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        else
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    }
    else
        e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

    string dir = (e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? "ASC" : "DESC";
    lastSortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection;
    lastSortMemberPath = e.Column.SortMemberPath;
    await UpdateData(e.Column.SortMemberPath, dir);

    // In my opinion, this last bit is redundant since data should come already sorted
    CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, e.Column.SortDirection));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Above solution is work fine for me. But It will be appreciated if any other solution in which no need to declare variable outside of sorting event.

Comment: If you don't want to manage sort direction yourself, you'll have to remove the `e.Handled = true` from your original code and let the DataGrid sort itself (no matter if you also sort data from server).

Comment: I have tried it before. But it sorts only data within current Page Size. Means I have page size of DataGrid is 20. So it will sorts within 20 records. But I need to sort from whole database table.

Comment: I'm not telling you to stop handling the Sorting event completely, just to remove the `e.Handled = true` line. You can still get the sorted data from your database using your `UpdateData` method, but you can also let the DataGrid sort itself. Both things aren't mutually exclusive.